# Need to pass data from one component to another component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I use `@Input()` to pass an ID from another component, but I initialize the ID with a number like this:

```
@Input() ServiceId: number=21;
```

How can I initialize the input with that number from the initial component? Do I  directly assign a variable to `@Input()`?

Answer (score 0):

You send the data to the child component via the parent component's template.

For your case, your parent component's template could look something like this:

```
<my-sub-component [ServiceId]="21"></my-sub-component>
```

If your parent component has a property called, e.g., `myServiceId`, you can pass that in as well:

```
<my-sub-component [ServiceId]="myServiceId"></my-sub-component>
```

Take a look at the documentation [here](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#sending-data-to-a-child-component) for more information.